# Get data from next page after providing Search Parameters using Mechanize and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, mechanize

I want to crawl data in

> http://dnre-mrne.gnb.ca/MineralOccurrence/default.aspx

From Browser, it's possible to get the tabular results (paginated) by providing "%" in reference number.

Following is my code snippet:

```
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MineralDBScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://dnre-mrne.gnb.ca/MineralOccurrence/default.aspx"
        self.br = mechanize.Browser()
        self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
                                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7')]

        self.br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        self.br.set_handle_robots(False)

    def select_form(self,form):
        return form.attrs.get('id', None) == 'MainForm'

    def scrape_state_firms(self, state_item):
        self.br.open(self.url)
        s = BeautifulSoup(self.br.response().read())
        saved_form = s.find('form', id='MainForm').prettify()

        self.br.select_form(predicate=self.select_form)

        self.br.form['ctl00$txtURN'] = state_item
        self.br.form.fixup()

        ctl = self.br.form.find_control('ctl00$reset1')
        self.br.form.controls.remove(ctl)

        self.br.submit()
        print self.br.response().read()

    def scrape(self):
        print 'Scraping all reference numbers by %'
        self.scrape_state_firms('%')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = MineralDBScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

After I run this code, my expecation is to get the tabular-data set according to the search parameter '%'.

But, I am getting the previous data i.e. the landing page where search parameters are available.

Please help me out. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Take a look at the submit button, there's some JS there that manipulates form fields, specifically __EVENT_TARGET and __EVENT_ACTION

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Submit1" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$Submit1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_Submit1">`

I see this in submit button. I am really unable to play with the parameters that's been passed to 
`WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()`